# Use aws cloud9 as VPS not IDE

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I want to use aws cloud9 as VPS not IDE, is it possible?
I made some progress already

using codecommit to push code from local pc to amazon service and when by running below command it's working:

```
forever stopall
git clone // clonning repo from codecommit 
forever start index.js
```

but I still have to open aws cloud9 on my browser and run above commands manually every time I pushed something. Is there a way to automate this?

p.s. lambda functions didn't work since it's not supporting git.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use AWS Cloud9 instead of an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein not necessary want to use AWS Cloud9 but find it more user friendly, I still don't understand how can I push my code to EC2 with git in all tutorials I have watches people uploading their code with FileZilla which is not a better option for me since it such a long process and im updating my code every 1-2 days. P.S. I'm only looking for free tier solution.

Comment: Is there any deference between cloud9 and EC2? I been told by people what its same with (both using EC2 server) but with IDE.

Comment: There is no additional charge for AWS Cloud9. It is basically a server installed on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: So Im still confuse how do I push from my local git repo in my pc to EC2 server?

Comment: You will need a repository that is accessible from all systems that want to use the code. For example, you could store code in GitHub or in AWS CodeCommit. Then, from anywhere on the Internet, you can push code into the repository or pull code from the repository. See: [Hello World · GitHub Guides](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I set up codecommit now I can push my code there, but I still don't understand how can I detect changes (commits) in codecommit and run script in my EC2 because right now I have to push code from my local pc when open putty and run all command manually

Comment: Yes, that is the way git works. You can obtain the latest updates via `git pull`. If you want that to be automated whenever code changes in the repository, you could setup a `cron` job to run the command at regular intervals.

Comment: yeah but cron job is won't be a solution since I need to restart node app to apply new code. So I can't just restarting by node app every 1 minute or so.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Take a look at: [Tutorial: Create a Simple Pipeline (CodeCommit Repository) - CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ok, I was following this tutorial you linked and this yt vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voWo0hF8mQQ
but build failing on codedeploy state

Comment: "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems."