# Detect change in CodeCommit and run command in EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to detect changes in my amazon codecommit repo and run following commands:

```
forever stopall
git clone // clone codecommit repo
forever start index.js
```

Right now I have to `git push` code from my local pc to codecommit and when open putty and run commands above manually every time. I wish someone know how to automate this process.

My goal is to push code from my local pc to EC2 as fast as possible without logging to EC2 instance with putty every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use aws cloud9 as VPS not IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691076/use-aws-cloud9-as-vps-not-ide)

Comment: Please stop spamming the site with the same question! You've asked it 3 time already.

Comment: @phd I haven't got an answer, I guess I have to rephrase my question.

Comment: There are many question at SO that never get answers. Repeating a question could bring downvotes and moderator attention instead of answers.

Comment: @phd well every time I created new post I get closer to getting correct answer so whats not very true

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Code Pipeline for that. https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/

Comment: ok, I was following this tutorial you linked and this yt vid youtube.com/watch?v=voWo0hF8mQQ but build failing on codedeploy state

Comment: "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems."

Comment: That is some other issue, is your problem of this question resolved? If yes, you may want to accept the answer and ask another question regarding new problem.

Comment: No my issue haven't been resolved since my goal is to push a code to EC2 but as I said its failing.

Comment: Attach your code commit, code pipeline and code deploy configs

Comment: configs? where can i find them?